# How to change url dropzone? URL dynamically with ajax success

Tags: dropzone.js

I read this: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically but i dont got success... :(
I have 1 form...

And i send the inputs with ajax.

The ajax returns the new id of user. in this moment i want to change de url dropzone for to set path to id of the new user.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "class/inserir.php?funcao=teste",
    data: formdata,
    dataType: "json",
        success: function(json){
        if(json.sucesso=="sim"){
            alert("Wait! Sending Pictures.");
                    this.options.url = "class/upload_img.php?"+json.id;
            myDropzone.processQueue(); 
        }else{
        location.href="home.php?ir=cad_animal&cad=nao&erro="+json.erro;
        }
    }
});

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#imagens", {

    url: "class/upload_imgteste.php",
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 1, // MB
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    dictResponseError: "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo!",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    thumbnailWidth: 138,
    thumbnailHeight: 120,

});
```

sorry for my bad english!

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 34):

You may add a function on dropzone's "processing" event listener.

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
```

Here is the link where I got the code and it works for me: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Set-URL-dynamically

Comment: Best answer here

Comment: Right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

change this

```
this.options.url = "class/upload_img.php?"+json.id;
```

to this

```
myDropzone.options.url = "class/upload_img.php?"+json.id;
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 6):

New answer for an old question only because I found this answer and the link to the dropzone wiki and didn't like it. Modifying the options of the plugin multiple times like that seems very wrong.

When dropzone uses some options it runs it through a resolveOption function passing in a files array. In the current branch you can define a function for the options: method, url and timeout.

Here's a complete working example including delaying for the ajax:

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

const doStuffAsync = (file, done) => {
  fetch('https://httpbin.org/get').then((response) => {
    file.dynamicUploadUrl = `https://This-URL-will-be-different-for-every-file${Math.random()}`
    done();//call the dropzone done
  })  
}

const getMeSomeUrl = (files) => {
  return `${files[0].dynamicUploadUrl}?sugar&spice`;
}

let myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  method: "put",
  accept: doStuffAsync,
  url: getMeSomeUrl
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.css">

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the URL dropzone posts to dynamically for each file, you can use the processingfile event and change the options.url.

```
<form id="my-dropzone" action="/some-url" class="dropzone"></form>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that worked for me (accept event callback):

```
$('div#dropzone').dropzone({
    options...,
    accept: function (file, done) {
        this.options.url = 'the url you want';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

BlueWater86's answer didn't work for me. But I agree that changing myDropzone.options.url each time is bad practice, and it actually doesn't work if you are dragging a lot of files into the uploader at the same time.

I wrote the following code and it works well for uploading one file at time and for many at a time. I'm using Backblaze B2 but it should also work for S3.

```
myDropzone.on('addedfile', function(file) {
  options = {
    filename: file.name,
    type: file.type,
    _: Date.now()
  };

  // Make the request for the presigned Backblaze B2 information, then attach it
  $.ajax({
    url: '/presign_b2',
    data: options,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
      file.dynamicUrl = response['url'];
      myDropzone.enqueueFile(file);
    }
  });  
});

myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr) {
  xhr.open("PUT", file.dynamicUrl); // update the URL of the request here
  var _send = xhr.send;
  xhr.send = function() {
    _send.call(xhr, file);
  }
});
```