# How do you change the url of Dropzone in Typescript?

Tags: dropzone.js

Ive read [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159834/how-to-change-url-dropzone-url-dynamically-with-ajax-success)  But the typescript definition of an instance Dropzone doesn't have an options property and if I change the url of the DropzoneOptions object later, the change isn't reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the only way I have found to do this is editing the index.d.ts file for Dropzone to remove `static` declaration of `options`.  Once I did that, the setup is pretty much like the previously linked post.